# Creating a toUpper function in C

Tags: c, toupper

I'm creating my own toUpper function in C, but keep getting a segmentation fault every time I attempt to run it. Can anyone provide me with any hints as to how to fix this problem?

```
int toUpper(char *str)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i< i <= strlen(str); i++) {
        if(str[i] >= 97 && str[i] <= 122) {
            str[i] = str[i] -32;
        }
    }
    return(str[i]);
}

int main()
{
    char string[20];

    printf("Enter any string:\n");
    scanf("%s", string);

    char result= (char)(toUpper(string));

    printf("The string in upper case is:%s\n", result);
}
```

Comment: Might want to change if(str[i] >= 97 && str[i] <= 122) to if(str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z') this is safer and easier to read.

Comment: You can't return or store strings with `int` or `char`. You have to use `char*`. Rethink the types of `toUpper` and `result`.

Answer (score 7):

You're running off the end of the string:

```
for(i=0;i< i <= strlen(str); i++) {
              ^--
```

e.g. a 10 char string has characters 0->9, but you're looping 0->10. Change `<=` to `<` so you stop at 9.

Plus, you haven't set any limit on your scanf, so if someone enters a 21 char string, you'll exceed the storage you've allocated the `string` array.

Comment: Not to mention returning `str[i]` will be garbage.

Comment: Ah yes. That too. hadn't even read that far down into the code.

Comment: And the odd conversion from `char *` to `char` and back for printing the string (which is now past the end of the string...)

Answer (score 2):

Recommend changing `toUpper()` to:

```
char *toUpper(char *str) {
  size_t len = strlen(str);
  size_t i;

  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z') {
      str[i] = str[i] - 'a' + 'A'; 
    }
  }
  return str;
}
```

1. Use correct index range `i < strlen(str)` vs. `i <= strlen(str)`.  This is the main issue. @Marc B
2. Change return type.  Suggested by @Weather Vane.  like `strcpy()`, `strcat()`
3. Calculate string length once, rather than many times.
4. Use literals that match your goal: `'a'` instead of `97`. @marsh
5. Use `size_t` for index and length.  That is the type return by `strlen()` and is the best type to use for array access.  Makes a difference with *huge* strings, but not with these simple examples.
6. This code does depend on ASCII.  This is often OK, but not completely portable.
7. Change 32 to `-'a' + 'A'` per @user295691

Comment: That's good. I noticed the type warnings in the other post I edited but let it go.

Comment: @Weather Vane True, on 2nd thought `char result= (char)(toUpper(string)); printf("The string in upper case is:%s\n", result);` is likely OP's seg fault source.  But with using your good idea about return value, which seems to be OP's goal, that problem goes away with `printf("%s\n", toUpper(string));`.

Comment: I would also add instead of `32`, you could use `('A' - 'a')` -- still ASCII-only, but avoids magic numbers.  Also, there's no reason to have the intermediate variable `s`, unless you change the loop to increment `s`.

Comment: @user295691 Agreed on both points, but used ('a' - 'A') for 32.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("The string in upper case is:%s\n", result);
```

result should be a char * but is a char.  This is probably where your seg fault is happening.  Other places include:

```
scanf("%s", string);
```

if the inputted string is longer than 19 chars, you could have problems due to string only being 20 chars long

```
  for(i=0;i< i <= strlen(str); i++) {
```

if str for whatever reason doesn't have an ending 0, you could seg fault there as well.

Answer (score 1):

Another major issue in the code is the for loop statement.

`for(i=0;i< i <= strlen(str); i++)
         ^  ^`

It's probably a typo, but the i < i < wont work.